# Powershell Reg.GetValue giving output as "-1" for actual value "ffffffff (hex) / 4294967295 (decimal)"

Tags: powershell

I ran below Powershell code and getting value as Indicated below:

```
$regOpen=[microsoft.win32.registrykey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey(‘LocalMachine’,$env:COMPUTERNAME)
$RegKey= $regOpen.OpenSubKey($reg)
$Enabled = $RegKey.GetValue('Enabled')
write-host "Enabled value is : $Enabled"
```

Output as below:

```
Enabled value is : -1

$enabled | Get-Member

TypeName: System.Int32
```

Value in Registry : ffffffff (hex) / 4294967295 (decimal)

Another method (Get-ItemProperty) gives correct decimal value 4294967295 as below:

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client\' -Name Enabled | select Enabled

   Enabled
   -------
4294967295
```

What I can do to get correct value 'ffffffff (hex) / 4294967295 (decimal)' from GetValue method?
Thanks.

Comment: What is $reg?..

Comment: Hmm this is false `0xffffffff -eq 4294967295` but this is true `(4294967295 | % tostring x) -eq 'ffffffff'`

Comment: Sorry, lost in the edit, here is $reg value (actually looking for TLS 1.0 enabled value):
"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\SecurityProviders\\SCHANNEL\\Protocols\\TLS 1.0\\Server"
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you might have guessed, this behavior is because `[uint32]::MaxValue` and the `[int]` value `-1` has the same binary representation (`0xFFFFFFFF`) in memory.

We can therefor get the correct unsigned value by converting to a byte array and then to the target type:

```
$binary  = [BitConverter]::GetBytes(-1)
$unsigned = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($binary, 0)
```

At which point you'll find `$unsigned` equals `[uint32]::MaxValue` as expected:

```
PS ~> $unsigned
4294967295
PS ~> '0x{0:X8}' -f $unsigned
0xFFFFFFFF
```

Comment: Thanks, that explains :)

Comment: @JustinD If my answer solves your problem, consider marking it "accepted" by clicking the checkmark on the left